# Can we get robbed of gold in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had about 6,000 gold before selling some stuff to Tonilia in the Thieves Guild. Then I decided to rest there for 2 days so that she gets more cash. I repeated this thing a couple of times and then continued my adventure.

Suddenly I noticed I have only 1,000 gold. I have no idea how I got to this amount. I haven't purchased anything so far. Did I get robbed in the Thieves Guild while I was resting? What happened to all my gold?

Comment: Stupid question - are you sure you were selling and not buying?

Comment: It's not a stupid question. I myself did very often sell when I wanted to buy or buy when I wanted to sell because the interface gave little visual clues that I was in the wrong section. I bet that's what happened here.

Comment: Yep. Pretty sure cause I don't buy anything cause I feel we can always get it sooner or later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you cannot get robbed in Skyrim. If you are selling items maybe you have 10,000 and just misread. Or maybe you were accidentally buying items from the shop keeper instead of selling to them.

It's also possible it's a glitch, but I can assure you no one can steal from you in Skyrim.

Comment: Thanks. It most probably must be a glitch in that area. I think so because I had 2 save files with the only difference between them being that I sat on a chair and did nothing but "wait" for 2 days (yes I saved before waiting and after waiting too, and yes, I'm a saving freak). A difference of gold was introduced in this waiting.

Comment: Hmm yeah i have seen a couple of question similar to this it must have be a glitch D:

Answer (score 3):

I have totally bought like 10k worth of items, thinking to myself "I don't remember picking that up, but I sure want to get rid of it."  Yay for quick-load.  It's also why I always quick-save just before bartering - just in case I do something stupid.

I have noticed items disappearing from me early in the thieves guild quests though.  I picked up the Thieves Guild armor upon entry into the guild, handed it to Jordis, then a bit later when I was transferring stuff to my various chests in Whiterun, 3/4 pieces of my Thieves Guild armor was gone (no idea what else may have been missing).  I think I just did something dumb, but it is remotely possible there's a bug in that area.