# Is it safe to carry lots of gold around?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there any need to store gold in chests in my home(s)? Can I be pickpocketed by NPCs in the game or otherwise unexpectedly lose gold or items from my inventory? Or can I safely carry all my gold around?

Comment: One of the only reasons, imo, to depositing gold, is when you know a quest will take your valuables from you for the duration of the quest. I have heard of being pickpockted, but I don't think it's part of the game.

Comment: related: [Can we get robbed of gold in Skyrim?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38354/can-we-get-robbed-of-gold-in-skyrim)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is safe to carry around all your gold, even <s>stolen</s> pickpocked gold, gold stolen off tables and coin purses: Gold is considered to be untraceable, and thus is not confiscated when you goto jail, according to [The UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Jail#Stolen_Items), and supported by the fact that gold doesn't gain a stolen caption in your inventory most of the time.

However, if you acquire gold with the stolen tag through currently unknown means, this gold will be confiscated when you go to jail, and should be stored in your house.

Comment: This is _incorrect_. Gold can be marked as stolen. Confirmed by myself and others in the comments on my answer. Pickpocketed gold doesn't appear to get marked as stolen, which is probably what led to this misapprehension.

Comment: I have acquired gold marked Stolen, which was confiscated by a guard. No idea where I got it, since pickpocketing and lifting coin purses from taverns doesn't appear to mark the gold Stolen.

Comment: I've updated this to include it, but I'm going to assume that 'stolen' gold is a bug until I see a reproducible way of getting it. If pickpocketing it and lifting it off tables doesn't mark it as stolen, and another way does I'm pretty sure it is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

If you're arrested with stolen gold, it will be confiscated along with any other stolen items in your possession.

Other than that, it is perfectly safe to carry gold around.

**Edit:** Doesn't match the UESP Wiki, however this is correct. See the comments. Confirmed that my gold is marked as stolen in game, and that stolen gold will be confiscated.

Comment: Are you sure on that @agf? http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Jail#Stolen_Items notes that gold is not taken when you are arrested.

Comment: I see that, but it doesn't square with my experience in game. My gold is marked as stolen, and if I put it in a container, it turns red. I discovered this when I had a 5g bounty in Solitude, so put my stolen gear in a barrel and talked to a guard, only to have all of my gold disappear. I reloaded and add my gold to the barrel. Can anyone else test if they get the same result?

Comment: Just tested this, and concluded that while pickpocketed gold is not marked Stolen, it IS possible to acquire Stolen gold somehow, and Stolen gold will be confiscated when you pay your fine. When I paid a 40g fine to a Whiterun guard he took around 100g and my gold was no longer marked Stolen, suggesting that I had about 50g Stolen gold and it was confiscated. Gold pickpocketed later didn't acquire the Stolen status. Perhaps gold marked Stolen is a bug?

Comment: Is it possible that stolen gold comes from when you take a coin purse from a house that is marked with 'steal' when you pick it up?

Comment: @JonathanDrain Thanks for testing; it's good to have confirmation. I don't see why it would be a bug, though? It seems more like a bug to me that pickpocketed gold _isn't_ marked as stolen.

Comment: @Jasarien I believe the gold I was carrying would have been stolen from containers in houses rather than Pickpocketed or picked up from the environment. I'd assume owned loose gold and coin purses would follow the same rules as other items, so probably they will be marked as stolen.

Comment: @agf Further testing would be necessary to determine what exactly causes gold to be marked as Stolen. I just lifted a coin purse from the Bannered Mare and it was not marked Stolen. I haven't tested coins picked from tables. It does appear that while gold can be marked as Stolen, stolen gold usually isn't marked.

Comment: I'm betting it is a bug, as gold is supposed to be untraceable. How is the guard supposed to know that that 5 gp was lifted off a merchant instead of found in a chest?

Comment: Also: Are you using any mods? What versions of the game are you playing?

Comment: @Canageek PC version here, no mods. I also tested stealing from a chest and stealing another coin purse, then stealing a coin purse while being noticed, and none of it was marked Stolen after I took it. It may be a bug, as there are reports of [other items being marked Stolen](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44376/why-some-items-appears-red-after-placing-them-in-my-own-house).

Comment: @JonathanDrain The gold in the container was marked as owned before you took it?

Comment: @agf Correct, the gold was red when I opened the chest, and no longer marked Stolen when I took it. The purse was marked "Steal" rather than "Take", also.

Comment: @JonathanDrain I'm not sure if this will be pertinent, but I think Canageek may also be interested in knowing the version *number*.

Comment: @Iszi It's whatever the current version is, as of 17th January 2012, as Steam automatically updates it.

Comment: @agf Gold being marked as stolen has never been my experience, I'm going to agree with assuming it is a bug.