# How can I separate a stack of an item in my inventory into "stolen" and "legally obtained"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Nidoru is an Iron Dagger collector. In her short 11 levels of being alive she has smithed, collected and stolen about 100 Iron Daggers.

The Iron Dagger stack is marked as stolen whether in her personal inventory or in a container. I'm pretty sure she has just stolen about 5 or 6 of those daggers (don't get me wrong, she **is** a thief).

How can I separate the 6 stolen daggers into a different stack of daggers, so Nidoru can have a stack of 94 "legally" obtained daggers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the top of the stack is always the stolen items first. So if you split the stack, say by using a container, you can just trim off the top of the stack which contains your stolen items.

You can tell you've run out of stolen items (daggers in this case) when your stack of daggers in your inventory is no longer marked as "stolen".

Comment: Do you know if it works the same for gold?

Comment: Gold is never considered stolen - see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47345/is-it-safe-to-carry-lots-of-gold-around

Comment: I am a very avid thief stealing everything from gold to clothes to potions to jewelry to the neat weapon from time to time.. This system for separating them has never failed and I simply keep my general items and my stolen items in separate containers.

Comment: @Resorath I've seen gold marked as Stolen before, and a few commenters in the thread you linked also agree that it can be.  (Now I wish I could down-vote a comment without flagging it.)

Comment: @Iszi I was going by the accepted answer on that page, as well as the information on UESP which I generally trust. I will change my commend if the accepted answer on that question changes.

Comment: @Resorath The answer was edited yesterday to concede the possibility of stolen gold.  Does that not satisfy your condition?

Comment: I tried this very carefully but it's just wrong. The items in the stack are not ordered by their stolen status. The best way so far is to drop the items, then pick those that are or are not stolen.

Answer (score 8):

- Step 1.  Find a container.
- Step 2.  Place daggers one by one into the container.
- Step 3.  Stop when the daggers in your inventory are no longer marked stolen.

At that point, all the daggers in your inventory are honest daggers, while all the daggers placed in the container are stolen.  If there were some honest daggers originally in the container - then the container is mixed.

---

If you're through with the daggers there's another way.  Find a vendor that doesn't buy stolen merchandise.  Sell all the daggers you can and you'll be left with the stolen ones.

If you just want counts... compare the counts from your item screen and the vendor's screen.  The vendor screen's count doesn't include stolen daggers.

Comment: Do you know if it works the same for gold?

Comment: I don't, because I don't know a way to get gold marked as stolen (picked gold isn't marked).

Comment: This whole "Gold [can|can't] be marked stolen issue." is getting old.  I think I'm gonna play-test it some this week.

Comment: Does not work, see my comment under accepted answer.,

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered that dropping a stack of items that has some stolen and some not seperates the stolen from the non-stole automatically. Just leave the stolen ones on the ground from there on.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The other answers do not work any more, the items are no longer ordered by their stolen status.